# Exiftool: Copying Nikoncapture to sidecar and back to another file

Tags: exiftool

I just read around the topic Nikon Capture data and exiftool but it is not getting to work. I want to copy the Nikon Capture setting from one file to another by a temporary file. I checked that in the file (.nef) is already the Nikon Capture Tags.

```
exiftool.exe -tagsfromfile  %1 -MakerNotes:NikonCapture "C:\Users\BENUTZER\Desktop\xmp.xmp"
```

I also tried

```
exiftool.exe -tagsfromfile  %1 -NikonCapture:all "C:\Users\BENUTZER\Desktop\xmp.xmp"
```

But I get the message that there is nothing to write or that the tags are not writable (I want to read?)

Anybody any idea how solve the problem? Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found a proper solution with exiftool.

The copying with:

```
exiftool.exe  %1 -MakerNotes:NikonCaptureData -b -U > "%temp%\xmp.mie"
```

and for applying to the image:

```
exiftool.exe "-MakerNotes:NikonCaptureData<=%temp%\xmp.mie"  -w! -b -U %1
```

I made a package with the zip files and [a instruction](http://rokdd.de/permanent:viewnx2-patch-adjustments) how to integrate in Nikon View NX 2

Answer (score 0):

I answered this on NerdAnswer: http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=397889

(but I notice now a problem with my first command to extract the information)

You have come up with a solution that works.  Just a few points:

1) -U is not necessary in your first command

2) The first command doesn't generate a MIE file, so an extension like .DAT or .BIN or maybe .NCD would be more appropriate

3) In your second command, the -w!, -b and -U are superfluous options

- Phil

Comment: This may be better as a comment

Comment: Thanks for feedback I am going to correct the issues you mentioned..